# Concurrent request in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to file Concurrent Client request on to Check my Server Capability.

How can I achieve it in node environment which is single threaded? I want to concurrently run below code in threads.

Below is my Code:-

```
var net = require('net');
var sleep = require('system-sleep');
var express= require('express');

module.exports = {

  Activation:function() {
    var client = new net.Socket();
    client.setTimeout(60000);
    var strSendData="6534265365342135425366532121323767";
    var sendData = Buffer.from(strSendData, 'hex');

    console.log('Connecting...');

    client.connect(8094, '192.168.126.129', function(data,err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Not able to connect with server');
      } else {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write(sendData);
      }
    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('Received: ' + data);
      client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
    });

    client.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Connection closed');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Just call it twice in a row. For example `Activation();Activation()` both requests will be made concurrently

Comment: Note that you don't need threads for concurrency. You just need asynchronous I/O. Coucurrent = parallel wait = single threaded, Parallel = parallel code execution = multi threaded